# Symfony throws error but not 404 page

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling, twig

The problem is I see trace error pages in production mode, in Symfony app.

I have this in app.php:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

And I have done:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was completely wrong! The purpose of the second parameter in `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);` is to enable/disable the `debug mode`. You can read the doc here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/environments.html

The issue was solved by setting to `false` the `debug mode`.